# Как осуществить вывод имен покупателей а так же количество их заказов в определенном году?

Tags: sql-server

вопрос на английском звучит так: Show first and last names of the employees as well as the count of their orders shipped after required date during the year 1997 (use left join)

и уже около недели я ломаю голову как это осуществить в sql server 
буду очень благодарен за любую помощь!
Вот структура бд : [cсылка](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ad43beb5737bc55c90d3b6dd120fcfe1316238ea/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f493236773954392e706e67)

Comment: Вы же пробовали написать выборку самостоятельно? что именно у вас не получилось? выбрать имена работников? выбрать количество заказов?

Comment: @PashaPash имена и фамилии работников выбрать получется) не получается придумать как должно выглядеть условие "на протяжении 1997г"

Comment: OrderDate >= '1997-00-00 00:00:00.00' and OrderDate < '1998-00-00 00:00:00.00'

Comment: @PashaPash для начала мне нужно преобразовать 1997-00-00 00:00:00.00 в datetime?

Comment: SQL Server сам преобразует

Comment: @PashaPash вот что получаю в ответ: Преобразование типа данных varchar в тип данных datetime привело к выходу значения за пределы диапазона.

Comment: вечно забываю про индексацию от 1... `where OrderDate >= '1997-01-01 00:00:00.000' and OrderDate < '1998-01-01 00:00:00.000'`

Comment: @PashaPash не подскажите почему когда я пишу < '1997-12-31 00:00:00.000'  
мне выдает ту же ошибку?

Comment: `year(OrderDate) = 1997` как вариант.

Comment: @teran Спасибо, работает!)
у меня получилось вот что `select firstname, lastname from employees join orders on  year(orderdate) = 1997`

в ответ я получаю имена и фамилии тех , кто совершал покупку в 1997, но как я понимаю выводится имя и фамилия для каждой покупки.
Как можно изменить код, чтобы показывало только уникальные имена и фамилии, не подскажите?

Comment: @teran спасибо, разобрался, стоило лишь добавить `DISTINCT` к `SELECT`'y